# TFS Build via Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-plugins

Friends,

I have already setup TFS build on my box. Currently the build can be triggered using VS IDE or Web interface. However i will like to hook existing TFS build process in to Jenkins as we use Jenkins as standard build tools for all platform builds. Is there any plugin available? I searched with available plugins but it has only MS build plugin.

Thanks
Bala

Answer (score 2):

There is a TFS Plugin available & also Jenkin-TF tool available. Check this link, it has been For detailed instructions on how to configure TFS & Jenkins

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/10/19/building-ios-apps-in-tfs.aspx